# How can i do this using sed command?

Tags: sed

Problem : Cannot insert a text using sed

content of file

```
aa=
```

i want to add a text after aa= using sed?

the output should be like below

```
aa=testing
```

Comment: With these types of question it's always absolutely trivial to produce the output you want from the input you specify, the hard part is not messing up other parts of your input file that you do not want to change. So, you might want to provide some more interesting input that includes cases that you think might be hard to [mis]identify.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it:

```
 sed 's/aa=/aa=testing/'
```

Comment: Lose the `/g` flag unless you want and need to perform multiple replacements on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `awk` if you like.

```
awk '/aa=/ {$0=$0"testing"}1' file
```

If you like to make sure it only replace line that only contains `aa=` and nothing more, do:

```
awk '/^aa=$/ {$0=$0"testing"}1' file
```